# Python - remove list duplicates that are in reverse order

Tags: python

Any ideas on tackling an issue I am facing in Python...

I have a nested list with items that are duplicated but in the opposite order (order stays the same but they switch in the middle):

```
links = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['g', 'h', 'e', 'f']]
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on the best way to remove the duplicates so I end up with:

```
links = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
```

I want to detect the duplicate and remove it, the first instance needs to be kept exactly the same and in the same order, so in the above example I am removing list items 1 (['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']) and 3(['g', 'h', 'e', 'f'])

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your coding attempt please

Comment: Can  `['h', 'g', 'f', 'e']` also occur and does it have to be considered as separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the other response but maintains the order of the original lists.

```
def get_uniques(links):    
    my_set = set([])
    my_selection = []
    for l in links:
        s = "".join(sorted(l))
        if not s in my_set:
            my_set.add(s)
            my_selection.append(l)
    return my_selection
```

And a cryptic one-liner-like (probably more efficient):

```
scheck = set()
survivers = [ (l, scheck.add("".join(sorted(l))) ) 
                         for l in links if  not "".join(sorted(l)) in scheck ]
result = [a for a, _ in survivers]
```

Comment: Eguaio, many thanks for your solution! This has had me scratching my head for some time! I felt sets were the way to go but exactly how I was unsure! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that! An equivalent solution could be written using a dictionary. A list could have been used instead of the set, but one important aspect is that set elements (and dictionary keys too) are hashed, so the "if s in myset" check is done in constant time. If it were a list, the time would be linear. That is the real gain in using a set (or a dictionary) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort and convert to strings all the items in your list:

```
l = [ "".join(sorted(l)) for l in links ]
```

The conversion allows you to use 'set' that guarantee no duplicates:

```
l = list(set(l))
```

Finally, convert the strings back to list of characters :

```
l = [ list(l) for l in l ]
```

Comment: I would note that this method is not order-preserving.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the elements of list and then remove duplicate.
Find my code and listsfinal represents your answer.

```
links = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], 

['g', 'h', 'e', 'f']]
links1=[]
for elements in links:
    elements=sorted(elements)
    links1.append(elements)
# print links1
linksfinal=[list(t) for t in set(tuple(element) for element in links1)]
print linksfinal
```

Comment: This is not order-preserving either.